# Call SelectMany on List of items and return item from list as parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query where I use SelectMany on a list of lists and then GroupBy 'Name' and the 'count' of the Lists and store the values in 'Value' and 'Count'.

```
var groups = originalList.SelectMany(fullList => fullList.ListOfItems, (fullList, details) => new { fullList.Name, fullList.ListOfItems })
                                   .GroupBy(x => x.Name,
                                    x => x.ListOfItems.Count())
                                   .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()});

//Do something with results        
foreach (var item in groups)
{
    var name = item.Name;
    var count = item.Count;
}
```

Now I want to pass the actual ListOfItems through to my final group as I would like to access that also.

So I want to end up with:

```
foreach (var item in groups)
{
    var value = item.Name;
    var count = item.Count;
    var list  = item.ListOfItems.   <-- I want this also
}
```

How do I modify this query to do this?

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs and expected sample outputs. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: why can't you add `.ToList()` at the end of this line `.Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()}).ToList();`

Comment: Currently `Count` counts items in each group, ignoring the `x. ListOfItems.Count()` value. Is this what you were planning to have?

Comment: I want to be able to see all 3 values in my final group, the Name, the Count of items and the actual list of items in that group.  If I add .ToList then I cannot get what I want, if I ignore x.ListOfItems.Count() then I do not have the count of the items

Comment: @HarryBoy You do *not* currently have the count of the items in `ListOfItems`. You have the count of items with identical name in the group.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I want the count of the identical names in group.

Comment: if you concentrate on just getting the list of items in the group then there is no reason to have the count, as it will be a property of the list itself.  So I think add the ToList and use the count method of that in your foreach loop . . .

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your `GroupBy` to keep `ListOfItem`, and add its count in the `Select`, like this:

```
var groups = originalList
    .SelectMany(
        fullList => fullList.ListOfItems
    ,   (fullList, details) => new { fullList.Name, fullList.ListOfItems }
    )
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => new { // Construct combined list of items
        Name = g.Key
    ,   ListOfItems = g.SelectMany(x => x.ListOfItems).ToList()
    })
    .Select(x => new { // Add count
        x.Name, x.ListOfItems, Count = x.ListOfItems.Count
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm am finding that the ListOfItems returned is the complete list of Items in the whole originalList. Where I need just the ListofItems that is associated with particular Name.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does far too much. It creates objects that duplicate `Name` as many times as the number of items in each `ListOfItems` and then you have to use `GroupBy` to de-duplicate `Name` again.

The natural group is already there: `originalList` itself. You only have to select items from that list and return their `ListOfItems` and its count:

```
from org in originalList
select new
{
    org.Name,
    Count = org.ListOfItems.Count(),
    Items = org.ListOfItems
}
```